# How to represent the variation of electrical resistance with frequency for ideal circuit elements?

Tags: resistance, frequency, ideal

Can anyone please help me a little and guide me through representing the variation of electrical resistance with frequency for an ideal resistor, coil and capacitor.

I will do all the work I can myself, I just need some guidance on how to start here.

SO far I only found connections between frequency and impedance on the web, so I'm really stuck, theoretically-wise.

Comment: An ideal resistor does not vary with frequency, and if you're also talking about ideal capacitors and inductances, they simply vary with the reciprocal of the frequency. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance for example.

Comment: Do you understand the s-domain?

Comment: @Felthry I can't say I'm familiar with it. Mind explaining it a little or showing me where I can research it a little? Theoretically I think I get this whole thing, but I don't know how to represent it graphically.

Comment: A simple web or wiki search will  answer this simple query

Answer (score 1):

An ideal element has no parasitics.
\$\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}} \$

Resistor: \$ Z = R_{ideal} \$
Inductor: \$ Z = j\omega L_{ideal} \$
Capacitor: \$ Z = \frac{1}{C_{ideal}*j\omega} \$

Real elements have parasitics, why? Because components don't superconduct, they all have some kind of metal in them and the metal has inductance and resistance. In most cases this can be ignored, but at high frequencies the effects of the parasitics become apparent.

Resistor: \$ Z = R_{ideal}\parallelsum \frac{1}{C_{par}*j\omega} +j\omega L_{series} \$
Inductor: \$ Z = j\omega L_{ideal}\parallelsum \frac{1}{C_{par}*j\omega} + R_{series} \$
Capacitor: \$ Z = \frac{1}{C_{ideal}*j\omega}+j\omega L_{series}+R_{series}  \$

[image]]
Source: [EMC Complicance Mag](https://incompliancemag.com/article/emi-in-components/)